# JavaFx JFoenix horizontal JFXNodesList

Tags: java, javafx, nodelist, jfoenix

I am trying to make the node list open horizontally but it open as vertically. Is there anyway to achieve this?
Thanks.

```
JFXNodesList buttonsNode=new JFXNodesList();
JFXButton val1=new JFXButton("1") ;
JFXButton val2=new JFXButton("2") ;
JFXButton val3=new JFXButton("3") ;

buttonsNode.addAnimatedNode(val1);
buttonsNode.addAnimatedNode(val2);
buttonsNode.addAnimatedNode(val3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rotate the JFXNodesList with setRotate(). The rotation occurs clockwise:

```
 0           down (default)
 90          left
 180         up
 270 (-90)   right
```

Of course, all interjacent values are also possible.

Example:

```
        JFXNodesList buttonsNode = new JFXNodesList();
        buttonsNode.setRotate(-90); // to the right 
        JFXButton val1 = new JFXButton("1") ;
        JFXButton val2 = new JFXButton("2") ;
        JFXButton val3 = new JFXButton("3") ;
        val1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: salmon");
        val2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue");
        val3.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgreen");
        buttonsNode.addAnimatedNode(val1);
        buttonsNode.addAnimatedNode(val2);
        buttonsNode.addAnimatedNode(val3);
```

This results in:

[image]

A good blueprint for the usage of the JFXNodesList is the source code of the JFoenix-demo. Download the source code JFoenix-master.zip from https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix. You can find the Java class for the JFXNodesList-demo at JFoenix-master\demo\src\main\java\demos\components\NodesListDemo.java.